# How to Validate value of string if it has duplicate value VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have problem in validating a `value` if it has a duplicate `value`.

For example, I've enter `201800001` and in that `value` it has a 3 value in the other table.

```
`201800001` = `1100`
            = `1100`
            = `1100`
```

My code is working and getting all the `value` even it the same but i want is if it has duplicate `value` automatically remove the other same `value`.
I want result is like this,

```
`201800001` = '1100'
```

The other same `value` is remove.

**This is my code so far.**

```
  If dgTitleList.Rows.Count = 0 Then MessageBox.Show("No records found to be generated", "No Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) : Exit Sub
    If cboNTS.Text = dgTitleList.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString() Then
        MessageBox.Show("The Title Status is already " + dgTitleList.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString() + ".")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim IsWip As String
    Dim rdSeq, wipSeq, listSeq, tnList, eno, epebid As String
    tnList = ""
    eno = tnList
    rdSeq = tnList
    wipSeq = tnList
    If txtRSUNO.Text = "" Then MessageBox.Show("Please input RSU number", "No RSU Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) : Exit Sub
    If cboNTS.Text = "" Then MessageBox.Show("Please choose new title status", "No RSU Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) : Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To dgTitleList.Rows.Count - 1
        If eno.Contains(dgTitleList("dcEPEBENO", i).Value) = False Then
            eno &= If(eno = Nothing, "", ",") & dgTitleList("dcEPEBENO", i).Value
        End If

        epebid = dgTitleList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        Dim stat As String = dgTitleList("dcIsWIP", i).Value
        Dim dtno As String = dgTitleList("dcTitleNo", i).Value
        Dim dseq As String = dgTitleList("dcTitleSeq", i).Value
        tnList &= If(tnList = Nothing, "", ",") & If(tnList.Contains(dtno) = True, "", dtno)
        If stat = "N" Then
            If rdSeq.Contains(dtno) = True Then Continue For
            rdSeq &= If(rdSeq = "", "", ",") & dseq
        Else
            If wipSeq.Contains(dtno) = True Then Continue For
            wipSeq &= If(wipSeq = "", "", ",") & dseq
        End If
    Next
    If chkIsWIP.Checked = True Then
        IsWip = "PHILARIS_RD_WIP..MS_Title_List"
    Else
        IsWip = "MS_Title_List"
    End If
    listSeq = rdSeq & If(rdSeq = "" Or wipSeq = "", "", ",") & wipSeq
    Dim RSUs As New List(Of String)
    RSUs.Add("RSU-" & txtRoD.Text & "-" & txtRSUNO.Text)
    CreateFolder(RSUs(0))
    Dim script As String = SetMainHeader(getScriptVersion("Tag Title Status"), txtRoD.Text, txtRSUNO.Text, epebid, "10", "UPDATE TITLE STATUS", "PHILARIS_RD")
    script &= returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "Header.txt", txtRSUNO.Text & "|" & eno.Replace(",", "','") & "|" & bookType & "|" & tnList.Replace(",", "','"))
    script &= If(rdSeq = "", "", returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "HistRD.txt", ""))
    script &= If(wipSeq = "", "", returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "HistWIP.txt", ""))
    script &= returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "break2.txt", "")
    script &= If(rdSeq = "", "", returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "UpdateRD.txt", cboNTS.Text & "|" & rdSeq))
    script &= If(wipSeq = "", "", returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "UpdateWIP.txt", cboNTS.Text & "|" & wipSeq))
    script &= returnScriptGenerated("TagTitleStatus", "Footer.txt", IsWip & "|" & bookType & "|" & txtRoD.Text & "|" & eno & "|" & listSeq & "|" & txtRSUNO.Text & "|" & "Update Title Status|")
    ScriptWriter("RSU-" & txtRoD.Text & "-" & txtRSUNO.Text, script)
    DBAexecScripts(RSUs, "RD_" & txtRoD.Text & ",RD_" & txtRoD.Text)
```

[This is the result when i run the program and enter a value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuEGm.png)

The `For Loop` is working if the `value` of I've enter is different to each other and also it working if the `value` is the same.
Now i said is validate the same `value`.

Comment: What data types are you working with?  `DataGridView`?  If you use data binding you can work with the underlying data object which is usually easier to manipulate.

Comment: Yes in the `DatagridView`.

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely benefit from a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

```
Dim valueHash = New HashSet(Of String)();
For i = 0 To dgTitleList.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim currentVal As String = GetStringExample(i)
    If Not valueHash.Contains(currentVal) Then
        valueHash.Add(currentVal)
    End If
Next
```

The above is a very distilled example, as I'm not able to follow your posted code easily.  If you can break apart your code a bit and implement [Single Responsbility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), working with it is going to be much easier.

Comment: Thanks sir, I'm gonna try your answer.

Comment: It works, yes it validate the same value, but when i enter a `value` and in that `value` has a different from each other. It also validate if it is different `value`.